# How to prevent overlapping of text label of checkboxes for inline checkboxes?

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following form written to have inline multiple `checkboxes`

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            <label for="banana" class="form-check-label checkbox-inline">
              <input type="checkbox" id="banana" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors }" />
               Bananas
            </label>
    
            <label for="Pineapples" class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Pineapples" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors }" />
            Pineapples</label>
           
            <label for="Woodapple" class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Woodapple" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors }" />
            Woodapple</label>
           
            <label for="Berries" class="form-check-label">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Berries" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors }" />
            Berries</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

But the issue is the text label of `checkboxes` gets overlapped with the next one,
[shown on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um3aF.png)

How do i prevent this overlapping and make the text clearly visible in all `checkboxes`?

**UPDATE**
I have made the changes according to what "linker" ( see below ) has suggested but i still get the same issue

code

```
       <div class="form-row">
            
            <div class="form-group form-check">
             
              <section class="checkbox-section">
                  <label for="banana" class="form-check-label">
                      <input type="checkbox"  formControlName="bananas"  id="banana" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.bananas.errors }" />
                      Bananas
                    </label>
            
                    <label for="Pineapples"class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox"   formControlName="pineapples"  id="Pineapples" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.pineapples.errors }" />
                    Pineapples</label>
                  
                    <label for="Woodapples"  class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="woodapples" id="Woodapples" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors }" />
                    Woodapple</label>
                  
                    <label for="Berries"  class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox"  formControlName="berries" id="Berries" class="form-check-input" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.acceptTerms.errors }" />
                    Berries</label>

              </section>

            </div>
      
          </div>
```

```
.checkbox-section {
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
  }
```

Result
[here is the generated checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFinu.png)

Comment: Please check the answer and let me know. Best wishes :)

Comment: @Linker hello thanks for the reply : ) i have applied your solution but still the same issue, i have updated my original post with your code and linked to the images with checkboxes that was rendered

Comment: I have provided a link of stackblitz link in answer section and it is working. Please check. Can you provide your problem in stackblitz then I might check where it goes wrong ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use section tag `<section></section>` link below=>

```
<form>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group form-check">
             <section>
          <label for="banana" class="form-check-label checkbox-inline">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="banana" class="form-check-input"/>
                      Bananas
                    </label>

          <label for="Pineapples" class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Pineapples" class="form-check-input"/>
                    Pineapples</label>

          <label for="Woodapple" class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Woodapple" class="form-check-input" />
                    Woodapple</label>

          <label for="Berries" class="form-check-label">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="Berries" class="form-check-input" />
                    Berries</label>
       </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**NOTE:** Please check the link [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-dynamic-nzbavd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)